# Jest Encountered Unexpected token with import statement

Tags: react-native, jestjs, enzyme

I've tried many fixes based on SO and GH answers but none have worked.

I'm trying to set up Jest and Enzyme for my React Native project but I can't get tests to run. Here's my current test file:

```js
import React from "react";
import { shallow, mount } from "enzyme";
// import MapScreen from "../src/screens/MapView";

describe("MapScreen", () => {
  it("should render tab bar icons", () => {
    expect(true).toEqual(true);   // just to get tests working at all!
  });
});
```

The error:

```
    Jest encountered an unexpected token

    This usually means that you are trying to import a file which Jest cannot parse, e.g. it's not plain JavaScript.

    By default, if Jest sees a Babel config, it will use that to transform your files, ignoring "node_modules".

    Here's what you can do:
     • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
     • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
     • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

    You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html

    Details:

    /Users/TuzMacbookPro2017/Development/QMG-local/APPS/ELECTRO/node_modules/expo/build/environment/validate.js:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){import { 
                                                                                                    ^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

      at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:471:17)
      at ScriptTransformer.transform (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:513:25)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/expo/build/Expo.js:278:1)
```

My config files:

```js
// jest.config.js
module.exports = {
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ["<rootDir>setup-tests.js"],
  transformIgnorePatterns: [
    "node_modules/(?!(jest-)?react-native|@react-native-community|react-native-elements)"
  ]
};


// babel.config.js
module.exports = function(api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ["babel-preset-expo"]
  };
};



// setup-tests.js
import Adapter from "enzyme-adapter-react-16";
import { configure } from "enzyme";
import jsdom from "jsdom";

import "react-native";
import "jest-enzyme";

function setUpDomEnvironment() {
  const { JSDOM } = jsdom;
  const dom = new JSDOM("<!doctype html><html><body></body></html>", {
    url: "http://localhost/"
  });
  const { window } = dom;

  global.window = window;
  global.document = window.document;
  global.navigator = {
    userAgent: "node.js"
  };
  copyProps(window, global);
}

function copyProps(src, target) {
  const props = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(src)
    .filter(prop => typeof target[prop] === "undefined")
    .map(prop => Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(src, prop));
  Object.defineProperties(target, props);
}

setUpDomEnvironment();

configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });


// package.json
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "eject": "expo eject",
    "test": "node ./node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js --watchAll"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo",
    "testEnvironment": "node",
    "globals": {
      "__DEV__": true
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/samples": "2.1.1",
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.3.4",
    "expo": "^32.0.0",
    "native-base": "^2.12.1",
    "react": "16.5.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-native": "0.57",
    "react-native-elements": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-geocoding": "^0.3.0",
    "react-native-global-font": "^1.0.2",
    "react-native-indicators": "^0.13.0",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scrollview": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-material-dropdown": "^0.11.1",
    "react-native-render-html": "^4.1.2",
    "react-native-uuid": "^1.4.9",
    "react-navigation": "^3.9.1",
    "react-redux": "^6.0.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-test-utils": "^0.3.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "sugar": "^2.0.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-preset-expo": "^5.0.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "^4.0.1",
    "enzyme": "^3.9.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.12.1",
    "fetch-mock": "^7.3.3",
    "jest": "^24.8.0",
    "jest-enzyme": "^7.0.2",
    "jest-expo": "^32.0.0",
    "jsdom": "^14.1.0",
    "mock-async-storage": "^2.1.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.8.6",
    "redux-mock-store": "^1.5.3"
  },
  "private": true,
  "rnpm": {
    "assets": [
      "./assets/fonts"
    ]
  }
}
```

I can't get even this simple test to run. I have actually been able to get that test to run on a different branch, and copied all the test-related config files from that branch to this one, but I'm still getting this error.

I know there are many posts about this around but none seem to help me. I hope someone can help me get this working! Thanks!

Comment: It _appears_ babel isn't processing. I'm not sure why that is in your case, or I'd post an answer. But anyhow I'd focus on that first.

Comment: can you share your babel config?

Comment: Thanks brian I've included my config.